# How to clean duplicate strings, not words from text

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

In sublime text, notepad++ this regex code helps to delete duplicate words:

```
\b(\w+)(?:\s+\1\b)+
```

substituted by:

```
$1$2
```

Is there a better way of cleaning STRINGS not just words, such as if you have this:

```
'i love this game','i hate this game','i love this game','i play this game','i like this game',
```

to get this:

```
'i love this game','i hate this game','i play this game','i like this game',
```

Comment: Only if your duplicate strings are adjacent.

Comment: @melpomene they dont need to be adjacent, but if I'm not mistaken it's not possible to remove first found string because groups don't exist in lookbehind. In his example afaics he wants to remove second 'i love this game' string (e.g. replace it with nothing) - which can't be done, but removing first 'i love this game' is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in a multiple step process in Sublime Text 3:

1. Search for `'[^']+'\K,` and replace with `\n`
2. Edit menu -> Permute Lines -> Unique
3. Search for `\n` and replace with `,`

Comment: Thanks, I'll let you know in the next 6hrs.